# Google Cloud Endpoints doesn't know about the Work class from Objectify 4 Transaction, causing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: objectify, google-cloud-endpoints

I created a very simple Objectify/Endpoints class.

```
import static mypackage.OfyService.ofy;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Work;

@Api(name = "testapi", version = "1")
public class TestEndpoint {

    @ApiMethod(name = "test.insert")
    public TestEntity insert(final TestEntity test) {
        test.setName("test");
        return ofy().transact(new Work<TestEntity>() {      
            public TestEntity run() {
                ofy().save().entities(test).now();
                return test;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The TestEntity is trivial (getters & setters excluded for brevity):

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {

    @Id long id;
    String name;
}
```

And I use the OfyService pattern from http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices#Use_Your_Own_Service

However, when I try to generate the Endpoints library, I get a ClassNotFoundException for Work. Full stacktrace follows:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:97)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:196)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.HandleGaeProjectChange.gaeProjectRebuilt(HandleGaeProjectChange.java:64)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.properties.ui.GaeProjectChangeNotifier.build(GaeProjectChangeNotifier.java:77)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/objectify/Work
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.MethodHierarchyReader.addServiceMethods(MethodHierarchyReader.java:174)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.MethodHierarchyReader.readMethodHierarchyIfNecessary(MethodHierarchyReader.java:44)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.MethodHierarchyReader.getEndpointOverrides(MethodHierarchyReader.java:99)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiConfigAnnotationReader.readApiMethods(ApiConfigAnnotationReader.java:184)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiConfigAnnotationReader.readEndpoint(ApiConfigAnnotationReader.java:82)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.generateForService(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:242)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.generateConfigObjects(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:227)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.generateConfig(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:176)
    ... 20 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.objectify.Work
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 31 more
```

I don't have similar problems with other Objectify classes I include in Endpoint classes (eg Ref, etc), and I have Eclipse (4.2) project set up to include the Objectify 4.0b1 library.

I get exactly the same error if I change the Endpoints class to use VoidWork:

```
@Api(name = "testapi", version = "1")
public class TestEndpoint {

  @ApiMethod(name = "test.insert")
  public TestEntity insert(TestEntity test) {
    final TestEntity newTest = new TestEntity();
    newTest.setName(test.getName());
    ofy().transact(new VoidWork() {

            public void vrun() {
                ofy().save().entities(newTest).now();
            }
        });
    return newTest;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include the objectify jar in the classpatch for endpoints.  This is found in endpoints.sh (in linux, not sure of the windows equivalent).  There is an entry in the script for classpath - just add the location of the objectify jar file.

Comment: How would one specify this in the Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I added the Objectify jar through Build Path Libraries pointing at WEB-INF\lib

Answer (score 0):

Details can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Setup) for the maven setup. If you just want to get up and running fast, go [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/objectify/objectify/] and click on the latest version of Objectify (currently `4.0rc2/`), then download the `objectify-*version*.jar`file.

In Eclipse: add the `objectify.jar` as well as [`guava.jar`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)  to `[Project]/war/WEB-INF/lib`. Right click on your project. Go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries. Click "Add Jars…", navigate to the aforementioned `/lib` folder, click OK (do this once for each jar).